# Find BigDecimal in a Set

Tags: java, collections, bigdecimal

Taking into consideration that

```
new BigDecimal("0").equals(new BigDecimal("0.0")) == false
```

How could I find BigDecimal in java.util.Set using 'compareTo' logic?

```
new BigDecimal("0").compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.0")) == 0
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What type of `Set`? `HashSet`, `SortedSet`, etc.?

Comment: Use a `TreeSet`, which uses `compareTo`, unlike a `HashSet`, which uses `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: I have found a bug in existing code. I'm trying to find neat way how to fix it.

Comment: @Deadpool OP already knows this, which is why OP wants `Set` to use `compareTo` instead of `equals`. OP is asking how to make `Set` do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which by default uses `compareTo()`, unlike a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which uses `equals()` and `hashCode()`.